# NFS connection in OS X Mountain Lion doesn't show files in Finder

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, nfs, slackware

I've got NFS set up as a server on my Linux 3.7.1 (Slackware 14) box. I'm able to connect to it using my OS X Mountain Lion client, but Finder will not show any files. However, if I run ls through the Terminal, I can see the files OK.

I'm able to upload and download files just fine, I am just unable to view the files. I'm sharing a mount point called `/mnt/data` which has a btrfs filesystem mounted on it. I'm guessing it may be permissions-related, but I've got `/mnt/data` with read/write access for everyone.

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  138 Jan  4 10:34 data/
```

Any ideas?

I'm connecting to the NFS share by using the Go menu and then clicking on Connect to Server...

My `/etc/exports` file has one entry in it that looks like this:

```
/mnt/data 192.168.1.188(rw,insecure)
```

`ls -al` results:

```
mini:Volumes mike$ ls -al
total 9
drwxrwxrwt@  5 root  admin   170 Jan  4 20:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  34 root  wheel  1224 Oct 21 10:45 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     1 Jan  2 08:01 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxrwxrwx+  3 root  admin   102 Aug 26  2011 Time Machine Backups
drwxrwxrwx   1 root  wheel   152 Jan  4 20:18 data
mini:data mike$ ls -al
total 29
drwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel         152 Jan  4 20:18 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 root  admin         170 Jan  4 20:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1 1000  _lpoperator   302 Nov 16 12:07 BitTorrent
drwxr-xr-x  1 1000  _lpoperator    16 Nov 21 12:46 Comics
drwxr-xr-x  1 1000  _lpoperator   148 Nov 16 11:35 Movies
drwxr-xr-x  1 1000  _lpoperator  8808 Nov 16 12:00 Music
drwxr-xr-x  1 1000  _lpoperator   718 Nov 16 12:11 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  1 1000  _lpoperator    82 Nov 16 14:29 Various Files
drwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         100 Dec 26 10:48 home-backups
dr-xr-xr-x  1 1000  _lpoperator   842 Dec  4 14:18 slackware
-rw-r--r--  1 mike  staff         384 Jan  4 20:18 test.pl
```

`test.pl` is the file that I have been testing with. I noticed that I can see it in the Finder always, even if I connect/disconnect. I am fairly sure that permissions are to blame, but I don't know which settings to change to get NFS to play nice with Finder.

Comment: Please post the full output of `ls -al` on the mount in OS X. Where is it mounted to, exactly? Are you connected via Finder (*Go » Connect to Server…*) or the command line (`mount_nfs`)?

Comment: @slhck - I always look forward to your answers...